# How can I set a custom permission class on DRF JWT views?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a custom permission class to refuse any requests that do not have the correct API key provided in the request headers, and I'm not sure how to add it to the Django Rest Framework JWT views, including `obtain_jwt_token`, `refresh_jwt_token`, and `verify_jwt_token`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add your permission class? and how do you planning to provide those api key/ credentials in a request?

Comment: How is that relevant to the question? I just want to set the permission classes for the JWT-related views. It's actually irrelevant _which_ permission classes I intend to use. If someone wants to answer the question using one of the default permission classes, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by extending the jwt-view and using the newly created view. See the example below,

```
# permissions.py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class MyPermissionClass(BasePermission):
    # do something with your permission class
    pass
```

```
# jwt_clone_views.py
from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken, RefreshJSONWebToken, VerifyJSONWebToken

permission_cls = {"permission_classes": (MyPermissionClass,)}
obtain_jwt_token = ObtainJSONWebToken.as_view(**permission_cls)
refresh_jwt_token = RefreshJSONWebToken.as_view(**permission_cls)
verify_jwt_token = VerifyJSONWebToken.as_view(**permission_cls)
```

```
# urls.py
from .jwt_clone_views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token


urlpatterns = [
    '',
    # ...

    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    # and so on
]
```

Here I created a new module named **`jwt_clone_views`** which takes the permission classes as a parameter.
In `urls.py` , I used the newly created views, which includes  **`permission_classes`**

---

Note : I didn't test the solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct solution. It is missing a couple small things: `jwt_clone_views.py` needs `from .permissions import MyPermissionClass` and `urls.py` should actually have `from .jwt_clone_views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token` (note the change from "jwt_clone_views" to ".jwt_clone_views")